# How to store ConversationHandler States?

Tags: python, database, telegram, telegram-bot, python-telegram-bot

I created a `ConversationHandler` function for my bot.

But the issue is I uploaded it to heroku and there my bot script is keep restarting after a specific time for that reason on every restart we need to start `ConversationHandler` again by sending a command and that's the problem.

So, I want to know is there any way that we store the `ConversationHandler` States or something on a database and load them to the script during restart so the `ConversationHandler` work automatically without sending any command.

Otherwise

Is there any other host website there script never restart.

**BTW I am using `python-telegram-bot` and I have a database account on firebase**

Answer (score 0):

PTB comes with a built-in persistence mechanism, see [this page](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/wiki/Making-your-bot-persistent). To make persistence store the data to a database, you'll have to use a corresponding subclass of `BasePersistence` or `DictPersistence`. Have a look at e.g. [`ptbcontrib/postgres_persistence`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/ptbcontrib/tree/main/ptbcontrib/postgres_persistence).
I also found this 3rd party [`firebase-persistence`](https://github.com/licht1stein/ptb-firebase-persistence), but the last commit is from Juni 2020, so I don't know how well it plays with the latest PTB versions.

---

Disclaimer: I'm currently the maintainer of `python-telegram-bot`

Comment: Is there any examples?? Please

Comment: Example for what exactly? there is the [`persistentconversationbot.py`](https://github.com/python-telegram-bot/python-telegram-bot/tree/master/examples#persistentconversationbotpy) example